# Use dispatch_get_global_queue() in dispatch_get_main_queue

Tags: ios, objective-c, multithreading, grand-central-dispatch

I have started learning "GCD".

I found that when we use the FirstWay, the `alertView` will be called after all the `NSLog` functions are done with print.

But when we use the SecondWay, the `alertView` will be called before the `NSLog` function.
Why do these two methods run different results? 
Can these two methods not be asynchronous methods?
My English is so poor, I hope somebody can understand my description. 
Thank you!

```
/* 
 *FirstWay
 */
//    dispatch_queue_t globalQueue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0);        
//    dispatch_async(globalQueue, ^{
//        for (int i = 0; i < 10000 ; i++) {
//            NSLog(@"i = %d", i);
//        }
//        
//        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
//            NSLog(@"i = %d", i);
//            UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Title " message:@"Message" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:@"Yes", nil];
//            [alertView show];
//        });
//    });

/* 
 *SecondWay
 */
    dispatch_queue_t globalQueue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0); 
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Title " message:@"Message" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:@"Yes", nil];
        [alertView show];

        dispatch_async(globalQueue, ^{
            for (int i = 0; i < 10000 ; i++) {
                NSLog(@"i = %d", i);
            }
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you are submitting a job (task) to a queue by calling the dispatch_async function. Feature of dispatch_async is that it returns immediately, and the submitted block will execute asynchronously in the background.Because UI related tasks run only in the main queue, so you need to return to the main queue if you are in the background queue. And you simply call the dispatch_get_main_queue() method to update the UI.

**Here in your case:**

In the first case you are submitting the task to the global_queue whereas in the second case you have submitted your task to the main queue.

In the first one , for-loop code is executed from the global_queue and task inside inner dispatch handler is dispatched to the main_queue where it updates the UI (i.e shows the alert view).

In the second one , you are simply submitting to main_queue and you are updating the UI (showing alert) and then you are dispatching to global queue to do for-loop task.

I hope now it helps if not ,feel free to comment.

**More Info:**

Don't get confused, **first** just look at the outer dispatch. You are dispatching something to work in the background.You are willing to do that task in the other thread so that your main thread won't have to wait for some long task.(if your main thread takes much time waiting for something then the OS kills your application so GCD is here to take us out of that easily).
**Secondly** just think the code inside of same outer dispatch as a instructions (line by line codes only). Don't mingle with the inner dispatch handler. **Third** Go through those line by line.Code upto the start of inner dispatch is the block of code you wish to do in the background.And the reason you nest the inner dispatch is to come out of that background thread(in most cases) in your first case you have done it to show the alert view after your for-loop code completes.

Comment: When you "run in the background", is that like camouflage? Like the predator?

Comment: And keep in mind, when using `dispatch_get_global_queue`, your task runs on whatever thread is available for the given priority - including the main thread. Also keep in mind that abuse of the priority bands can lead to priority starvation - for example, scheduling a lot of high or default priority tasks can prevent low priority tasks from ever running.

Comment: @quellish, it's not like camouflage in the background. One thing, you cannot predict is ,when does the background task gets a turn of it's execution. One submitted synchronoulsy can be estimated but one submitted asynchronous is like impossible to predict. And, by the way , priority starvation you told is very important while doing background execution.

Comment: @Bikram. The second way can do what I want. But why the first case the NSLog method will block the main_queue? Does it mean that, if I submit a task to global_queue, then I submit a UI task to main_queue (Like the first case), the main_queue need to wait for global_queue run to end?